# GRASS and SAGA do not appear in QGIS processing toolbox?

Tags: installation, saga, qgis-grass-plugin

I installed the latest version 3.24.1-Tisler and also installer GRASS 7.8.7, SAGA 7.8.2 and PCRaster using OSGeo4W (from 7.4.2022). All Plugins have been activated in QGIS as well as the settings in the Processing Options. While the PCRaster appears/dissapears according to setting (activate/deactivate) GRASS and SAGA do not appear in my processing toolbox. Thus I cannot use them in my Graphical Modeler. Why does that happen? Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 15):

Recently GRASS and SAGA integration system changed within QGIS. You must enable the SAGA and GRASS provider plugins to keep using the grass and saga tools.[image]

Comment: Both are core plugins my QGIS version. I only needed to enable them by clicking the checkbox.